# Why is androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat.size() on a null object reference is thrown

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-lifecycle

In my application, this exception is thrown when I try to move the application into the background.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat.size()' on a null object reference
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:500)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:510)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1503)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1308)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4943)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4231)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4290)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap28(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1665)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Can somebody explain me why this exception is thrown?

Comment: Did u get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In `FragmentActivity` which is extended by `AppCompatActivity` whenever onSaveInstanceState is being called`mPendingFragmentActivityResults` is being null in your case. This field `mPendingFragmentActivityResults` is used for keeping map from where Frament.startActivityForResult() is called so it can dispatch result back using onActivityResult to appropriate fragments. One thing that could cause this is probably you have set Don't keep Activities setting on in Developer Options. Anyway debug these classes and try to find the cause.